# make if statement with several exists conditions insert when true

Tags: mysql

Sup folks!

**I try to:**

insert a row in a table IF and only IF two different rows exist in two other tables.
if there is a user with id 1 AND there is a thing with id 2, then a third table should be populated with 1 and 2.
I work with predefined statements or whatever they are called, and want to do this in one big query, so as not to fall for some race conditions where one checks if condition is true, another one deletes a row, and then the first one inserts despite the other one removing a row needed in the condition.

The query that does not work looks like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE userId=16) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM things WHERE thingId=2) THEN INSERT INTO user_thing(userId, thingId) VALUES(2,3) END IF;
```

**Tries:**

I tried doing this and it works.

`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE userId=16) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM things WHERE thingId=2);`

I also tried this and it works:

`INSERT INTO user_thing(userId, thingId) VALUES(2,3);`

So I do not belive its something weird with my tables, since it works when I divide the statements.
But it does not work when I try to make it into an if then statement in one fell sweep.

I guess there are fancy stuff like joins unions etc, but Im a noob and really want to write something I understand instead of copy pasting something I dont, and also I do get obsessed of WHY something is not working rather then getting a completely different solution.

I did try to look for solution, and also here on stackoverflow, but cannot find why an

`IF EXISTS AND EXISTS THEN statement END IF;` wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `INSERT...SELECT` instead of `SELECT...VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO user_thing(userId, thingId) 
SELECT 2, 3
FROM dual
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE userId = 16) 
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM things WHERE thingId = 2);
```

You can omit `FROM dual` if your version of MySql is 8.0+.

Comment: I tried it and it works. But it feels unnatural to me, backwards or as if the insert statement is somehow detached from the rest of the query. Perhaps because I did not write it or dont understand enough (obviously) Could you elaborate on what is going on in your answer. Also perhaps why my query did not work?

Comment: The select statement returns 1 row with 2 columns (there are no names for the columns because they are  not needed) only if the conditions in the WHERE clause are satisfied. The table `dual` is a special one-row, one-column table used in cases like this where you need only 1 rows not related to any table. You can find the documentation for INSERT...SELECT here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Ah. I guess I only seen select being used where one mentions actual existing columns, and putting erm, what in column 2 and 3 that actually dont exist. Thats where my mind blows up. haha. But thanks, I will look at the link you posted, thanks. Ill wait before I mark as answered just incase someone can "fix" my nonworking solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the whole condition in parentheses?

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE userId=16) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM things WHERE thingId=2)) THEN INSERT INTO user_thing(userId, thingId) VALUES(2,3) END IF;
```

Comment: already tried that. Not working, several ifs, a select before each exists in the parentesis, even begin and end as mentioned is some answers to query questions. This really bugs me x)